# NUnit SetUp function is not running before my tests

Tags: c#, nunit

I am new to NUnit and am trying to use the `[SetUp]` feature to be called before my tests so that I can avoid repetition. Here is an excerpt from my test file:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ThermostatDotNet.Controllers;



namespace ThermostatTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ThermostatTests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
           var thermostat = new ThermostatController();
        }

        [Test]
        public void ReturnsCurrentTemperature()
        {
            thermostat.Reset();
            int actual = thermostat.GetTemp();
            int expected = 20;
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
```

However in the test the error reads `the name thermostat does not exist in the current context` - have I set this up incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `thermostat` a field -- currently it's just a local variable in your `Init` method.

```
[TestFixture]
public class ThermostatTests
{
    private ThermostatController thermostat;

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
       thermostat = new ThermostatController();
    }

    [Test]
    public void ReturnsCurrentTemperature()
    {
        thermostat.Reset();
        int actual = thermostat.GetTemp();
        int expected = 20;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```